# Get the cookies set by a JavaScript code using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying to do a PHP cURL request to a webpage that contains HTML code which sets a cookie.

I want to get this cookie then (using PHP too)

My current cURL request code (with explaination comments)

```
// Create cURL request with the required data.
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1813252164.1533305377; __test=29eed463641411464ada487a670d2be2',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
    'Host: example.com',
    'Pragma: '
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");

// Execute the cURL request and save the result into a string.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

So, let's assume our site is `http://example.com` - It should set a cookie using a JavaScript code.

I am able to get this cookie currently using this method:

```
echo $result; // Echo the cURL request result (which is a JavaScript code)
// Now, the above echo should set the cookie because it is in the JavaScript code
echo "The cookie is: ".$_COOKIE['MyCookieName'];
```

**EDIT**: I've just noticed that I must refresh the page so I can echo `$_COOKIE['MyCookieName']` :/

So, this works! But it works with browsers only while I am trying to make an API service.

Like: I want my script to work on another PHP script like:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/MyPHPscript.php");
```

But the result of this is `The cookie is:` only (empty, because `file_get_contents` can't execute JavaScript codes).

I am trying to solve this for 2 days but I failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `file_get_contents`, use cUrl again?

Comment: @LucaKiebel - Same?